# Aliased associations must have unique aliases

Tags: sequelize.js

In accordance with the documentation on creating my associations in [pairs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#creating-the-standard-relationships) and using [multiple associations on the same model](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#multiple-associations-involving-the-same-models), I get the error of

> "You have used the alias author in two separate associations. Aliased
>   associations must have unique aliases."

My author associations are;

```
User.hasMany(CourseRequest, {
  as: 'author',
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'authorId',
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isUUID: {
        args: 4,
        msg: `author must be a valid ID`,
      },
      notNull: {
        msg: `author is required`,
      },
    },
  },
});

CourseRequest.belongsTo(User, {
  as: 'author',
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'authorId',
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isUUID: {
        args: 4,
        msg: `author must be a valid ID`,
      },
      notNull: {
        msg: `author is required`,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have `as: 'author'` twice, change the name of one of  the alias

Comment: Managed to solve it. That format is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I was initially calling a function where the model is being used as

```
require('foo').bar()
```

instead of

```
const {bar} = require('foo'); 
bar();
```